# XMLParser Gwt

Tags: xml, gwt, xmlparser, java

Пытаюсь разобрать xml-файл, который получаю через сетевое соединение.

```
   <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
   <result id =\"result\">
       <connectionValue>1</connectionValue>
   </result>92
```

Использую такой код для разбора xml-файла

```
 Document result = XMLParser.parse(connectionXml);
 NodeList l = result.getElementsByTagName("result");
 for (int i = 0; i < l.getLength(); ++i) {
     if(((Element)l.item(i)).getTagName().equals("result")) {
         NodeList lst = ((Element)l.item(i)).getChildNodes();
         for (int j = 0; j < lst.getLength(); ++j) {
            valueArray[j] = ((Element)lst.item(j)).getNodeValue();
         }
      }
 }
```

Проблема в том, что все элементы в массиве valueArray равны null, а должно быть, после разбора вышеуказанного xml-файла, `valueArray[0] == "1"`.

Answer (score 1):

Всё потому, что connectionValue на самом деле имеет внутри себя текстовую ноду и уже у неё есть значение, равное единице. В то время как nodeValue для самого connectionValue  = null. Так что поведение парсера валидное. У меня сейчас нет под рукой GWT, так что покажу на примере стандартного явского парсера.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import java.io.StringReader;

/**
 * @author Sergey Mashkov
 * @since 20.01.2011
 */
public class Main {

    private static final String XML_INPUT = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
            "   <result id =\"result\">\n" +
            "       <connectionValue>1</connectionValue>\n" +
            "   </result>";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(XML_INPUT)));

        Node connectionValueNode = doc.getDocumentElement().getElementsByTagName("connectionValue").item(0);
        System.out.println("Should be null: " + connectionValueNode.getNodeValue());
        System.out.println("Should be 1: " + connectionValueNode.getChildNodes().item(0).getNodeValue());
    }

}
```

Comment: Никогда бы не подумал. Спасибо.

Comment: Это правильное поведение. Так прописано в спецификации DOM.